# Master concurrent programming in java

Tags: java, concurrent-programming

I want to master concurrent programming.
I heard that there are good books for concurrent programming in java by Doug Lea

- [Concurrent Programming in Java™: Design Principles and Pattern (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310090)
- [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)

Which book should I read first ? Are there other books. If anyone can tell me also guide me how practice this topic.

Comment: Perhaps you can read both at the same time.

Comment: @MarkByers wait, surely you don't mean _...concurrently‽_

Comment: Lea's book is from 1999, Goetz's book is from 2006. There has been some advances (e.g. `java.util.concurrent`) between those dates, so I recommend JCIP. If you master it, you master more than most Java programmers do.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/133242).

Comment: @JoonasPulakka The subject of Doug Lea's book *is* the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: @EJP: Oops, I wouldn't have imagined that, given that the book is from 1999 and `java.util.concurrent` was included in JDK5, year 2004.

Comment: why the down vote and where should i ask such question if SO is the best place to ask experts

Comment: @EJP, I think the confusion may stem from that *Java Concurrency in Practice* is co-authored by Doug Lea, however its principal author is Brian Goetz.

Comment: @user4o01 - 1) do you need to ask?  2) not our concern ... since SO is not a recommendation service.

Comment: @JoonasPulakka Nevertheless it is so. Read the book and learn. Your comment would make more sense if the book had come *after* JDK 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Java Concurrency in Practice* is the more recent of the two, so I recommend that. It covers lots of stuff, including the new concurrency utilities, which the other doesn't. However, CPiJ also contains stuff which is still relevant and is not repeated in JCiP, so you may want to check that out later too.